# Accessing value in nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am writing a text-based game in python for my first scripting project and cannot figure out how to access the last value in my nested dictionaries. I am trying to access the values for the key "item", so that when the player enters a room it'll show the item in said room. then with input from player the item will be added to inventory. I am struggling, so I appreciate the help.

```
rooms = {'Living Room': {'South': 'Study', 'North': 'Kitchen', 'East': 'Bedroom', 'West': 'Bathroom'},
    'Bedroom': {'North': 'Dining Room', 'West': 'Living Room', 'South': 'Sunroom', 'item': 'Glasses'},
    'Dining Room': {'West': 'Kitchen', 'South': 'Bedroom', 'item': 'Napkin'},
    'Kitchen': {'South': 'Living Room', 'East': 'Dining Room', 'West': 'Basement', 'item': 'Cheese'},
    'Basement': {'East': 'Kitchen', 'South': 'Bathroom', 'item': 'Catnip'},
    'Bathroom': {'East': 'Living Room', 'North': 'Basement', 'South': 'Walk-in Closet', 'item': 'Water'},
    'Walk-in Closet': {'North': 'Bathroom', 'East': 'Study', 'item': 'Shoes'},
    'Study': {'North': 'Living Room', 'East': 'Sunroom', 'West': 'Walk-in Closet', 'item': 'Cotton Balls'},
    'Sunroom': {'North': 'Bedroom', 'West': 'Study', 'item': 'Cat'}
}
```

Comment: What would be the expected output?

Comment: To access values in python use [] for example to get the value of the item in bedroom: `bedroomItem =  rooms['Bedroom']['item']`

Comment: Use .get and provide a default value otherwise it will fail for "Living Room"

Comment: okay thank you, I will try both of those! for the game, once the player enters a room I have to display each item in said room. Then will have to allow player to add to inventory.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of the solutions in the comments is as follows.

```py
roomName = 'Bedroom' # Select the room the user is currently entering.
roomItem =  rooms[roomName].get('item', 'Nothing') # 'Nothing' when no item in the room
```

This way you can select an item for every room, and in case no item is present, 'Nothing' is returned. You could also return `None` or any other value as default.